# How to disable hover tags and put them in the below bar

Tags: tags, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I literally searched like crazy but I couldn't find it..

But I really wanna disable the hover tags, like and reblog on my tumblr page.. Does someone know how I can fix this?

Theme used: http://cocorini.tumblr.com/theme #07 Tea Origami
Tumblr: http://simmer-sammsz.tumblr.com/

Already thank you so much for looking for me!